# Script error while serving react app from a subdirectory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, craco

I'm trying to serve a react application (created using [craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco)) from a subdirectory (https://my-domain/app). Following the steps of [this](https://skryvets.com/blog/2018/09/20/an-elegant-solution-of-deploying-react-app-into-a-subdirectory/#an-overview-of-the-more-elegant-solution-with-base-url-element) guide, and modifying nginx config's location to `/app`, I do get the static content, but some chunks generate the following error in Chrome:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' ... main.b5d3f270.chunk.js:1

Digging in, I noticed nginx returns an html page instead of pure javascript code, and the offending `<` is (probably) the beginning of `<!doctype html>`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   ...
</head>
<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    ...
    <script>
        !function...
    </script
</body>
```

This only happens when I serve the app from the sub-folder.

Any idea what the problem is?

A similar, unanswered question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57661080/error-when-serving-react-app-from-subfolder).

Comment: Have you configured the `homepage` in package.json, [as described here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths)? Does craco even implement this?

Comment: @ajrussellaudio. Yes, I followed the guide to the letter. I don't know regarding craco, but it seems like a major drawback if it does not support such a basic feature.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the problem was with nginx configuration, not with React. I was missing a directive to tell nginx to ignore the 'app' part of the URL, and to load files from a different directory. Doing the following solved the problem:

```
location /app {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.html =404;           
}
```

Similar solutions are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53207059/react-nginx-routing-to-subdirectory) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias).